# How to convert images into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I faced a problem when converting images into array, when reshaping the array this shows to me

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 43200 into shape (3,120,160)
```

This my code:

```
img_size = 224
i = 0
for _file in train_files:
    img = load_img(data_dir + "/" + _file , target_size=(224,224))  # this is a PIL imageflowers[0], target_size=(224,224))
    img.thumbnail((image_width, image_height))
    # Convert to Numpy Array 
    x = img_to_array(img)  
    x = x.reshape((3, 120, 160))
    # Normalize
    x = (x - 255.0) / 255.0
    dataset[i] = x
    i += 1
    if i % 250 == 0:
        print("%d images to array" % i)
print("All images to array!")
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to isolate the problem? Given your code, it seems that you are trying to resample the array as if it was an image. This is something that you cannot do by reshaping the numpy array. The exception is raised because 3x120x160=57600 is not equal to the product of the dimensions of the input.  Also you may try `numpy.array(img)`, instead of using `img_to_array`, for which I don't have any reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array has 43200 elements, and the shape that you want (3, 120, 160) would require 57600 elements. The product of the dimensions has to be equal to the size of the array for numpy to be able to reshape it.

Maybe if you reshape it to (3, 120, 120) it would work, but i guess you need to check the dimensions of the original image to get the results you want.